# CP437 writing dash sign ─

Tags: php, character, codepage-437

Using sprintf need a fill up a character https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2500

On console unix:

```
php > echo sprintf("%'-7s", '');
-------

php > echo sprintf("%'─7s", '');
�7s
```

A sign "─" is cp437 dash.

I need result:

```
───────
```

TEST: https://3v4l.org/JsAv6

This works:

```
php > echo sprintf("─", '');
─
```

Example:

```
echo sprintf("%'-7s", 'a');
------a
```

using dash will not work:

```
php > echo sprintf("%'─7s", 'a');
�7s
```

Comment: It's `"\xC4"` if you want it in that codepage, but your script is UTF-8 still. Also the display on the console is somewhat irrelevant unless the environment was also set to that charset. (You didn't explain enough on the whole context.)

Comment: A dash sign is utf-8 and it is not possible print using sprintf() even when your try iconv to cp437 or utf-8. https://3v4l.org/HApnQ#output

Comment: You can't use Unicode symbols as part of sprintfs´ syntax. Hencewhy didn't you try CP437 for the "dash" via `"%'\xC47s"`? It does [exist in that codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) as single-byte character. Isn't that your very question?